# how to show number of likes as a number on an imageview

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uikit, uilabel

I am working on a social networking app, at one point users can like a comment another user wrote down. Now I have an imageview holding an image representing that thing the user wrote, I want to be able to show on the top right corner of that image a small number with a number of how many likes he got, how can I do that?

Comment: When ever asking a question like this add some code so we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply put a `UILabel` with the number of likes on top of the `UIImageView`?